# How Filebeat deployed with Sidecar can load balance log sending with logstash deployed with Deployment

Tags: kubernetes, logstash, load-balancing, filebeat, elk

I built my system on k8s, where the app's logs are left as files in ephemeral storage, and filebeat, which I deployed with sidecar, collects them and sends them to logstash remotely. Logstash then loads the collected logs into ElasticSearch.

In other words, the app and filebeat exist as multi containers in the same pod, and logstash is additionally deployed as a Deployment to be HPA. filebeat accesses logstash's k8s Service as a vip endpoint.

The problem with this is that filebeat and logstash send logs over the beat protocol, and unlike http, this tcp connection is not one-time, so sometimes the connection is congested to a specific logstash pod, and when the logstash pod is spun up when traffic increases, the traffic is not distributed to the newly spun up pod.

I know there is a way to apply load balancing to logstash output via filebeat.yml settings. However, this approach requires a trusted, fixed endpoint to access the logstash pods, so I'm wondering if I should apply StatefulSet instead of Deployment. Furthermore, using this approach, I can't dynamically add pods that are auto-scaled by HPA to the load balancing.

I'd like to avoid using StatefulSets as much as possible because they're harder to manage than Deployments, and I'd like to have a way to use HPA because the traffic in my app can sometimes be 10x as heavy, so the logs are likely to grow as well.